# Why onChange inside input type text not working if input not come from typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 text field look like this :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="input1" onchange="doSomething();" disabled/>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function doSomething(){
 alert('Changed!');
}

$("#input2").change(function(){
 $("#input1").val(this.val());
});
```

> **My Problem are :**
>
> When i change value of input2 , i hope input1 will do doSomething
>   cause the value has changed. But my problem, it's not wokring for me
>   right now. Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this).val()` or `this.value`. `val()` is jquery method so you need to use jquery `$(this)` selector.

```js
$("#input2").keyup(function(){
 $("#input1").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1"  disabled/>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
```

Comment: Your code working well and answers my question perfectly. Thank you.